# Get access to particular item's layout in list view

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, adapter, listactivity

In my android app my Main `Activity` extends `List Activity`. I store there elements called Items, their layout is defined by itemLayout xml file and I use custom adapter (called `ItemAdapter`) to transfer data to List View in Main Activity. In itemLayout there's an `ImageView` and my aim is to change its image when user clicks on the particular item in list view. In my opinion the easiest way to achieve that is to get access to particular item's (the one that was clicked)  layout, there find the `ImageView` and call method `setImageBitmap`. How can I "find" this layout of clicked item? I tried many things in method:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

}
```

but nothing worked. Do I have to add anything to my ItemAdapter? Or is it possible to do in `onListItemClick(…)` but I can't find out how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're thinking about it in slightly the wrong way. Adapter's are a way to map data to views.  So if you want to change how a particular view looks for a given position, you need to change it's correlating data so that the rendered View then changes. Attempting to modify a view directly kinda goes against how adapters are meant to be used.

So in your case, when a user clicks on an item.  Find that item in your adapter via the position number.  Then update the item and ensure notifydataset is called.  Meanwhile, your adapter's `getView()` will then handle displaying the appropriate image.

Comment: That is definitely the best solution. Thanks

Comment: i was struck in a different issue, your first para gave me what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you need to modify clicked item layout, right? Use argument from onListItemClicked:

```
v.findViewById(<your_img_view_id>)
```

For better performance use view holder.

Comment: Yes, this approach give the result I want, but my aim is to make changes permanent.I forgot to add that list view is connected with search function and every time user enters anything, changes made with this approach disapper. Or maybe there is a way to get item's view only by its position? Then I could change the view every time data set changes.

Answer (score 0):

`onListItemClick` is fired when you press on an element of the `ListView`. If you want to retrieve the element in the dataset, you can simply invoke

```
l.getItemAtPosition(position)
```

the returned value has to be casted to the specific object

Answer (score 0):

Yes It is possible in your custom `adapter` class in the `getView()` mtheod u can change imageview bitmap by clicking on it

see this code

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View rowView = convertView;
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.playlist_item, null);

        final ImageView im = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.favorite);
        im.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Do your stuff here

            }
        });

        return rowView;
    }
```